# How to force client to update google play services?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My application use google cloud messaging service that required google play services version 5 or later.
How can i force client to update it's google play services without user doing anything ( if version is below 5) ???

Answer (score 1):

Devices running Android 2.3 or higher that have the Google Play Store app will automatically receive updates to Google Play services. The users who meets the above requirement will always get the latest version of google play services. You can read more on https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html